# How to save a list with records in it to print to a text file Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to write my list strOtherLine to a text file but I only get the last record of my list instead of all the records. So I say if I got these 3 in my list I only get the last record in my textfile.

```
 [**********, 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
 [**********, 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
 [**********, 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
```

Code:

```
if (strDdtype == "P" and len(strPc_AcctNo.strip()) or strDdtype == "C" or strDdtype == "S"):
       boolHasDirectDepositData = True
       intOtherRecs = intOtherRecs + 1
       boolHasOther = True
       if strDdtype == "S":
            strThisType = "Savings"
       else:
            strThisType = "Checking"
                    
       if strDdtype == "P":
            strThisRoute = strPc_Route
            strThisAcct = strPc_AcctNo
       else:
            strThisRoute = strBankRoute
            strThisAcct = strBankAcct
                        
            
       strOtherLine = [strSsn,strThisType,strThisRoute,strThisAcct]
       print(strOtherLine)
       if boolHasDirectDepositData:
          #===Writing to the text file
          with open(fc_otherfile,'w', newline='') :
              directdep = csv.writer(t, delimiter="\t")
              directdep.writerow(strOtherLine)
```

Comment: Use `'a'` mode to append the file. `'w'` replaces the file.

Comment: Or open the file before the loop.

Comment: fyi an empty string is false, so your if can start with `if strDdtype == "P" and strPc_AcctNo.strip()` without the `len`, and you don't need `()` around the whole thing

Comment: so will that show my records in the list I need my if statement to be true @Barmar as well and this the only place I can set it

Comment: When the condition is true it will add the line to the file.

Comment: Each line or just last line?

Comment: I need to create a new file every time not  add to the file @Barmar

Comment: If you create a new file each time through the loop, it will just have one line.

Comment: So it's basically no way to show everything in my list in my text file?

Comment: I can print my list before I write to a text file and it show everything  @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `w` mode in `open()` overwrite the file in every time (Creating a new empty file). You should use the `a` mode, in this case the if the file doesn't exist the script creates a new one but it is exists then the script appends the new lines to the file.

**Example code:**

```
import csv

strOtherLine = [
    ["**********", "Checking", "0000000000", "############"],
    ["**********", "Checking", "0000000000", "############"],
    ["**********", "Checking", "0000000000", "############"],
]

my_csv_file = "test.csv"


with open("test.csv", "a") as opened_file:
    directdep = csv.writer(opened_file, delimiter="\n")  # Used "\n" for better reading
    directdep.writerow(strOtherLine)
```

**Content after first run (File didn't exist):**

```
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
```

**Content after second run (File existed):**

```
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
['**********', 'Checking', '0000000000', '############']
```

Comment: In a comment above the OP said "I need to create a new file every time not add to the file". Why was this answer accepted?

Comment: That doesn't look like a proper CSV file, it shouldn't have the brackets, quotes, or spaces.

Comment: The script writes a nested list to the csv file so the brackets and quotes are correct in that case.